# Find textbox by name in a list of textboxes

Tags: c#

Given a list of `RichTextBox`, I would like to access one by its name.

So for example:

**EDIT**
I shouldn't have used the loop in the question. I am trying to access the name without a `for` loop.

```
public RichTextBox boxFinder(List<RichTextBox> boxes)
{
    return boxes.Find("boxname")
}
```

Comment: If you make that `n` a capital `N`... what happens? Perhaps you could detail what you're actually having trouble with? Why doesn't what you have work?

Comment: What are you asking? You have it except for the capitalization. You could of course run a LINQ query, but thats just a foreach behind the scenes...

Comment: See edit. I want to know if there is a way to use the list functions to find it instead of a loop

Comment: var mybox = boxes.First(box => box.Name == "boxname"); (using LINQ!)

Comment: @failedprogramming, why not put that as answer. So that, it will be useful for future readers.

Comment: @Rahul I wasn't sure if LINQ was acceptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method would be to use `FirstOrDefalut`

```
return boxes.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "MyName");
```

`First` will throw if there is no matching element. Note that this essentially performs a foreach that breaks after an element is found under the hood.

Comment: I will put the `foreach` version of answer. Will you +1 me too :)

Comment: @Rahul, That depends on the quality of the answer :) I'm sure it will be fine though.

Comment: Nah!! was just kidding ... people are much happier with `LINQ` answer. Anyways, +1 to you for another valid way.

Comment: @GrantWinney I actually thought the same thing and had to look it up to discover otherwise. I would definitely use this one in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Find is a function which takes a predicate (that is, a delegate which returns a bool).  You can call find using lambda:

```
public RichTextBox boxFinder(List<RichTextBox> boxes)
{
    return boxes.Find(box=>box.Name == "boxname");
}
```

Of course wrapping it in a function like this probably doesn't buy you much.